# C# Unit Test MOQ Method for GetAccounts not being tested

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, moq

I'm learning to create unit test methods for a bank application as part of my assignment and I'm having an issue:

The test method `GetAccounts()` is not being tested for some reason on Visual Studio. the Output message I get is

> "Discover test finished : 0 found"

This is the test method block below.

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetAccounts()
{
    var testAccount = this.MockDatabase.GetAccounts();
    Assert.IsNotNull(testAccount);
    Assert.AreEqual(4, testAccount.Count);
}
```

How can I make Visual Studio discover the test and give me some result?

If anyone wants me to post more of my codes, and not just the snippet above let me know. I'm happy to give you more info.

Comment: Has the class also an attribute?

Comment: Make sure the test class also has `[TestClass]` attribute. Show the full test.

Comment: Ah yes, it does have an attribute. I didn't included it in that piece of code. But thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the test class also has `[TestClass]` attribute

```
[TestClass] //<--- Test classes must have this attribute to discover test methods
public class AccountTests {
    IDatabase MockDatabase;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Arrange() {

        var accounts = new List<Account>
        {
            new Checking( new Customer(1, "Alex", "Parrish"), 12, 30.00M ),
            new Savings( new Customer(2, "Alex", "Russo"), 12, 29.00M ),
            new Checking( new Customer(3, "Emma", "Swan"), 12, 30.00M ),
            new Savings( new Customer(4, "Henry", "Mills"), 12, 30.00M )
        };

        var dataMock = new Mock<IDatabase>();
        dataMock.Setup(_ => _.GetAccounts()).Returns(accounts);

        //...code removed for brevity

        MockDatabase = dataMock.Object;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetAccounts() {
        var testAccount = this.MockDatabase.GetAccounts();
        Assert.IsNotNull(testAccount);
        Assert.AreEqual(4, testAccount.Count);
    }

    //...code removed for brevity
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, it does have an attribute. I didn't included it in that piece of code. But thank you.